# Parfor works with test data but not real data

Tags: matlab, matrix, regression, parfor

I am using Matlab 2016a. I have four matrices of size 2044x1572x84 and am trying to regress each column of each matrix to produce a new 2044x1572 matrix of regression coefficients. I need to use parfor; a for loop would take way too long.

When I use the below code using test data (e.g. using rand to make four matrices of 50x50x40) the code executes with no errors. However, when I try using the same code in a cluster with the full 2044x1572x84 matrices I get a transparency violation error with regards to the table: **Error using table (line 247) Transparency violation error.** I've tried modifying the table code to fix this but only get a suite of other errors.

I'm unsure how to fix the error in this case, particularly given that the success of the code seems to be dependent on the size of the input data. I'm not particularly familiar with parfor, and any feedback on what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
COEFF_LST=ones(2044,1572);

parfor i=1:2044
for j=1:1572

ZZ=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_L2_LST(i,j,:));
XX=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_L2_ONDVI(i,j,:));
YY=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_WB_85(i,j,:));
LL=squeeze(ARRAY_DETREND_L2_CNDVI(i,j,:));

T=table(ZZ,XX,YY,LL,'VariableNames',{'LST','ONDVI','DROUGHT','NDVI'});

lm=fitlm(T);
array=table2array(lm.Coefficients);
COEFF_LST(i,j)=array(3,1);

end
end
```

Comment: Transparency errors can also occur when you try to add variables to the main body of a parfor loop, see: [Lorens blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/#11). Are you sure you did the exact same things with your test data? Why dont you try to put the inner for-loop into a subfunction. Is it necessary that you assign the names inside the table and why dont you create the array/matrix directly?

Comment: Would you please edit the above code to make it is self-contained (i.e. define all inputs such that I can copy-paste and run it)? See also: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `table` constructor uses `inputname` under certain circumstances - that can cause transparency violations inside `parfor`. I realise it's inconvenient, but perhaps you could try "hiding" the `table` call inside a separate function. I.e.

```
parfor ...
    T = myTableBuilder(ZZ,XX,...);
end

function t = myTableBuilder(varargin)
    t = table(varargin{:});
end
```

Comment: When trying this I get the error "Function definitions are not permitted in this context." I'll keep trying.

Comment: Try putting `myTableBuilder` in its own `myTableBuilder.m` file. (The most recent versions of MATLAB do allow you to define functions inside a script `.m` file)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I talked to my PI and realized I can construct my code without using "table" at all; this is what I did and it works.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'm getting a transparency error with `table`, so a simple solution that works is to not use `table`.

In this case the code would be:

```
Predictor_Matrix=horzcat(ZZ,XX,YY);
    lm = fitlm(Predictor_Matrix,WW);
```

This works on a cluster without throwing any errors.